# Refine image segmentation based on a set (or atlas) of 2d binary masks

Tags: python, semantic-segmentation, crf, image-registration

I'm wondering if there are techniques to extract features from a set of 2D binary masks and use them as *a priori* rules to constraint and refine an incoming mask.

To better understand what I'm talking about, let's call each mask of the set **A_X** (A_1, A_2...), and let's consider they are coming from the same 3D objects (slight variation in size and aspect ratios) with different planar projections. And let's call the incoming mask **M**, also coming from the same type of 3D object with a planar projection that has been already covered with the **A_X** set.

I've investigated the contours of the shape and the relationship between points of the contours to encode the "path" it follows so that I can refine the contours of the **M** but it didn't work well.
I've also investigated the morphological techniques (erosion, dilation, smoothing, ...) but they tend to worse the incoming mask **M** because they is no rules to apply the morphological operation only to specific parts of the **M**.

I've already investigate the Statistical Appearance models but it seems that they require the extraction of landmarks from the incoming mask **M** to refine it, but my problem is that I'm not able to extract the landmarks from **M** as it is too noisy. (I think I can retrieve landmarks from **A_X** masks but I can't find any matching in **M**). Here is the link of a library (called [Menpo](https://www.menpo.org/)) I've investigated.

I've also tried to perform registration (using ANTs for example) from the images in the "atlas" to the new image but here again if I only apply affine transformation, the obtained registered masks are too far from **M**, and when I apply deformation, I'm getting close to **M** but I only want rigid transformation as I know that the mask can't be deformed in my use case.
This technique is a also computationally expensive as it requires several registration, but we can imagine ordering **A_X** based on the projection in a kind of decision-tree shape so that we can parse the tree based on the distance with each node (we perform a registration at each node of the tree and compare the distance with **M** and based on the distance we go left or right or we stop)

I'm going to investigate the Conditional Random Fields technique (as in [this link](https://github.com/hkchengrex/CascadePSP)) but the main problem is that I'm worried the raw image can't be used because post-processing has been applied to **M** and it doesn't follow the regular gradient of the raw image.

PS: There is no code in this question because I'm looking for techniques and not a particular way of solving a specific problem.